# VS2013 Bowser Refresh Doesn't Show Updated Code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded my OS from Windows XP to Windows 7 and installed Visual Studio 2013. All my previous sites were built in VS2010 so there was a bit of tinkering to get the sites working.

Now everthing is working apart from one thing. Once the sites are started in debug mode it is imposible for me to update the browser with any changes that are made. I've tried using the Browser Link Feature in VS, ctrl+F5 and even a clear cache browser add on which all refresh the page but don't show any changes made to the code.

The only way I can view any code changes is to run Start Debugging again... which makes the software completely unusable!

I've even built a new VS project that has default pages within it and that doesn't don't work either so it can't be anything within my sites.

I've found a few posts from people with similar issues but most of them haven't resovled the problem and the fixes suggested didn't work for me.

Does anybody know what this issue is?

Comment: I have also tried updating to VS2015 to see if that fixed the issue but it hasn't. I can run the site in Debug or without debugging but I still have exactly the same issues!

Answer (score 0):

Your appSettings section should have `<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="true" />` and in web.config: `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="%your_framework_version%" />`.

You can find more details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew... I did try that but unfortunately it still doesn't work?

Comment: @Pinchy And what about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063985/visual-studio-2013-changes-not-showing-in-debug)?