# Visual Studio Possible Cache Error C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, caching

I am currently working on a project with a coworker which starts a service which starts up a website.  To run everything, I build my project on visual studio, start the service, go to the url (hosted locally on my machine) and the view which I setup appears.  My view is a .cshtml file which, in this case, contains a nicely formatted form.

I recently decided to remove one of the form items.  I deleted the appropriate snippet of html code in my project, and pushed the updated file to our version control system.  My coworker pulled from my version, and was able to 
build and start the service, and the deleted form field didn't show up.  However, on my machine, with the same version, the deleted form field still shows up, despite the fact that all of the code that makes the form field exist does not itself exist.  Rather, when I look at the source for the page using Ctrl + Shift + I, the html for the deleted field is still there, but this is not in alignment with the code on my IDE, visual studio, where I did delete that snippet.

I've tried rebuilding, cleaning and building, restarting the service, un and then reinstalling the service, and rebooting my computer and I'm still having the problem.  The website does not start without the service, so I know that everything is wired up correctly in that department, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why the html won't update.

I tried clearing out all my cookies and cached images and files (using Chrome as my browser btw) and also tried emptying the cache and doing a hard reload in my browser, but nothing seems to be working.  Is there a step that I'm missing where something could be cached?  Maybe in the visual studio building steps?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What source control solution are you guys using?

Comment: We are using Subversion

Comment: have you had a look at these SO answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063985/visual-studio-2013-changes-not-showing-in-debug

Comment: I just did and none of the solutions worked, although they all got my hopes up.

Comment: Question...did you try in another browser?...also, are you running your site on IIS Express?...which version of VS are you using?

Comment: I tried using another browser; same problem.  No, I am not using IIS Express I am self hosting with a windows service.  Also, I am using VS Professional 2015

Comment: clutching at straws now but what about putting break points in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved
Solution: Deleting the old project files that were still in the file explorer (but not on subversion), uninstalling the service, building, and then reinstalling the service solved this problem.